# Inherit Abstract model and add new field

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I need to inherit `mail.group` kanban view (`mail.view_group_kanban`). But some of the fields in this kanban view is defined in `mail.thread` model. Now my requirement is, i need to display count of members in a group on kanban view.To do this i have inherited `mail.thread` model and added new field. But i getting an error:`Field`new_field`does not exist.`

I have tried below code:

***.py**

```py
from openerp import models, fields, api, _
class mail_thread(models.Model):
   _inherit = 'mail.thread'
   _columns={
       'new_field': fields.char(string='New Field')
   }
```

***.xml**

```xml
<record id="view_group_kanban_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">view.group.kanban.inherit</field>
  <field name="model">mail.group</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="mail.view_group_kanban"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <field name="alias_domain" position="after" >
            <field name="new_field" />
          </field>
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_kanban_footer_left']" position="after">
                <field name="new_field" />
            </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Did you get solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You should define class definition like below:

class MailThread(models.AbstractModel):

```
  _inherit = "mail.thread"
```

Best Thanks,

Ankit H Gandhi.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why this makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

just code like this :

```
from openerp import models, fields, api, _

class MailThread(models.AbstractModel):
_inherit = 'mail.thread'
_columns={
   'new_field': fields.char(string='New Field')
}
```

but if you want to override fields in AbstractModel ,I dont know for it .

 thanks